# mimes:pdf don't work in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, validation, pdf, mime

I have searched in several pages for this problem. Everyone said pdf format should be validated by using **mimes:pdf** in rules. But whenever I use like this, the **validator** always fails. Can I get any suggestion for this problem?

Here's my validator code:

```
$rules = array(
    'pdf_file_1' => 'mimes:application/pdf,jpg,jpeg,png,bmp',
    );
    $validator = Validator::make($request->only('pdf_file_1'), $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back()->with('error',trans('sale/message.error.file_format'));
    }else{}
```

Comment: Add your validation code...

Comment: added the validation code.

Comment: I assume your validation is held within the controller yes?

Comment: yes. I have added in controller. Is that a problem?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: OK, let me try first.

Comment: It also don't work. Anyway, thx for your reply.

Comment: What did you remove to replace it with? There's a lot of unneeded code you have.

Comment: I have remove all my codes and I replace your code at the start of the function. Which codes are unneeded codes? Can you show me? I admit that my codes are not very well because I am just a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this is how you'd set out your validation whereas I believe yours is throwing an error:

```
public function uploader(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'file' => 'mimes:pdf'
        ]);
    }
```